# the argument of function 'argmax'

Tags: functions

In mathematics, argmax stands for the argument of the maximum, that is to say, the set of points of the given argument for which the given function attains its maximum value.[From Wiki]

We have the $k\in argmax_{z\in S}\left\{ p_{i},p_{z}\right\} $, and $S$ is a set, suppose $p$ is a vector, $p_i$ means the $i$-th element, so does the $p_z$.

Here is my question:can the $k$ attain the value $i$?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how $\arg \max$ works. With $\arg \max$, there is a function  $f : D \to R$ which you are optimizing from it's domain $D$ to its range $R$.

$\arg \max$ is like a function $\arg \max: (D_f \times R_f) \to D_f$ that takes a function $f$ and gives you a value $\hat d \in D_f$ such that there exists no other value $d \in D$ where $f(d) > f(\hat d)$.

The way you posed your question, this is the only way I could really interpret it: You want to find index $i$ of the largest value $p_i$ such that there exist no values $p_z \text{ for } z\in S$ such that $p_z > p_i$.

For this, we'd say the following:

$$
\underset{i}{\arg\max} \ \{\ p_i\ |\ \not \exists z \in S\ \ ( p_z > p_i )\ \}
$$

Here we can say that $f : \mathbb{N} \to \{\ p_i\ |\ \not \exists z \in S\ \ ( p_z > p_i )\ \}$. It's a function that takes an index $i$ that gives us a value $p_i$ that conforms to your original constraint $\not \exists z \in S\ \ ( p_z > p_i )$. So when we use $\arg\max$, we specify that we're looking for the value $i$ that maximizes $f$. If we want $k$ to be equal to that maximal argument, we'd simply say

$$
k = \underset{i}{\arg\max} \ \{\ p_i\ |\ \not \exists z \in S\ \ ( p_z > p_i )\ \}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, i think that i didnot present my confusion clearly,What if the value that maximizes $f$ isn't just one? Then $arg max_{z\in S}\{\ldots\}$ might be a subset of $\{i,z\}$

Comment: suppose that both $p_i$ and $p_j(j\in S)$ maximized $f$. whether the domain of $argmax$ is $S$? or, $\{i,S\}$

Comment: In the case that there is more than one argument in the domain that maximizes $f$, $\arg\min$ will be a set of those arguments. You can also assume that in the case that there is only one such argument, that it returns a set consisting of only one element.

Comment: well, the question i doubt is whether $k$ can attain $i$? after all, $i$ is not included in set $S$